# "The dark oxen that turn the millstones of the world"

Tags: philosophy

I'm trying to make sense of a Terence McKenna [quote](https://youtu.be/EZAMKn2xr9E?t=8m22s), here with more context:

> You know, you have to get a job, your first love is not your last love, slowly this pristine shining belief in perfectibility is eroded by the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune. *You know, the dark oxen that turn the millstones of the world.*

What did he mean by that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for a lit-crit discussion.

Comment: Is that against the rules or something? If so, is there another stackexchange site more suitable for this? Or perhaps another website? Thanks

Comment: Lit-crit is off-topic, but it's not entirely clear to me that this is lit-crit.

Comment: @PeterShor- I'm assuming that OP understand what *dark, oxen*, and *millstones* are and that it's the metaphor that's in question.  We might be able to guess at what McKenna meant, but we can't know for sure.

Comment: Millstones grind things down. Oxen power the millstones that grind things down. Here, he talks about one's idealism being eroded -- ground down -- by the millstones which are powered by these dark oxen. The oxen are dark because their work is dark, unpleasant, evil: to grind down the optimism and idealism and belief in perfectibility of the world. As in the old apocryphal saying: *illegitimi non carborundum*. Only here we need the (pseudo-) Latin term for "dark oxen" rather than "illegitimi". This is litcrit, so I can't post a formal answer, the Q is off-topic on ELU, but there you go.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, the oxen are "getting your first job", "realizing your first love isn't forever", etc, things which would tend to undermine your idealism, your belief in the perfectibility of the word: the very details the devil is in.

Comment: @DanBron It may be literary interpretation, but it's not litcrit. You can tell because what you wrote is intelligible.

Comment: @deadrat Not bad for unpacking McKenna... maybe a machine elf whispered in my ear.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Interpretation requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to try to interpret this at a literary level, but I'm pretty sure it's a metaphor referring to this:

[image]

in which an ox (or other animal) is used to do the hard work of grinding the corn necessary to feed people.

Comment: I don't understand. That ox is white.

Comment: It's a metaphor.

Comment: @DJClayworth What's a meta, for?

Comment: @DanBron - I never meta phor I didn't like.

Comment: You could ask about this on the site where we discuss the site. After all, that's what we've got meta phor.